# Is it possible to include method in TypeScript interface?

Tags: typescript

Just a simple question I was thinking about, is it possible to include method or function in an interface as following:

Waiting for your comments and ideas about possibilities or issues doing this:

```
export interface INewsletter {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  release_date: any;
  filename: string;
  original_filename: string;
  notification: boolean;
  file: File;
  newsletterTranslations: any;
  translations: any;
  newsletterFiles: any;
  newsletter_files: any;

  myMethod() { something to do } // My method here
}
```

Comment: @JuanMendes FYI, Java 8 allows you to provide default implementations for interface methods, like what they're asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interface is a contract. You can specify the interface has a method but you can't include an implementation. So adding `myMethod() : void;` is valid but *not* `myMethod() { something to do }` as this includes a implementation/body.

```
export interface INewsletter {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  release_date: any;
  filename: string;
  original_filename: string;
  notification: boolean;
  file: File;
  newsletterTranslations: any;
  translations: any;
  newsletterFiles: any;
  newsletter_files: any;


  myMethod():void; // replace void with any other return type or any
}
```