# Is it possible to create an interface in a typescript method?

Tags: node.js, typescript, oop, interface

**Minor note:** [Is it possible to include method in TypeScript interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47517125/is-it-possible-to-include-method-in-typescript-interface) may seem similar but it's asking the reverse of what this question is.

I have a typescript method that uses an `options` parameter that works and compiles fine:

```js
  async addKickingRule(options: KickingRuleOptions = {
    time: 60 * MINUTES,
    privileges: ALL_PRIVILEGES
  }) {
    ...
  }
```

It uses an interface defined elsewhere:

```js
interface KickingRuleOptions {
  time: number,
  privileges: Privileges[],
  channel?: string,
  userID?: string,
  ipAddress?: string
}
```

Again, this works fine. However I feel it would be easier for my colleagues if the interface was defined in-the body of the method.

**Can I use an `options` object in a typescript method and define the options interface in the body of the method?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
async addKickingRule(options: {
  time: number,
  privileges: Privileges[],
  channel?: string,
  userID?: string,
  ipAddress?: string
} = {
  time: 60 * MINUTES,
  privileges: ALL_PRIVILEGES
}) {
  ...
}
```